# Is user's facebook ID always constant for specific user that returns from facebook API?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use facebook login button to register or login user to my android app.

After getting permission from user; i get user email, facebook ID and authorization token from facebook API.

Early on, i was handling all authorization, logging in and registering processes with user's email. For example; i was checking if user registered to my server with querying his/her email. But, i noticed that main email of facebook account can be changed. So, i decided to use facebook ID of user for all operations.

I want to be sure; is user's facebook ID always constant for specific user that returns from facebook API? Can it be change in any case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. The ID is always constant in your App. It is App Scoped though, so it will be different in another App.

Comment: So, considering your answer; if i try to get same user's "user facebook ID" from IOS, will facebook API return another ID? If yes, still i don't have a constant unique value to identify my users. With "App Scoped", do you mean the App that i registered to facebook development zone?

Comment: one app = one id. you can have several platforms per app. just try/test it.